# My GY-MAX30100 pulse oximeter issue with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno

I connected the purple oximeter (GY-MAX30100) to the Arduino Uno with the following connections.

```
OXIMETER       ARDUINO UNO
VIN              5V
GND              GND
SCL              SCL
SDA              SDA
INT              D2
```

It shows me inaccurate measurements.

```
13:16:02.851 -> Pulse oxymeter test!
13:16:02.851 -> BEAT
13:16:02.851 -> BPM: 8616.35 | SaO2: 92.01%
13:16:03.055 -> BEAT
13:16:03.055 -> BPM: 4313.73 | SaO2: 92.66%
13:16:03.089 -> BEAT
13:16:03.089 -> BPM: 1209.15 | SaO2: 92.74%
```

I used this sketch from github
https://github.com/xcoder123/MAX30100/blob/master/max30100.ino

This is the sensor[image]

**EDIT**

I have run an I2C scanner and this is the result: I2C device found on address 0x57. The library has the same address hard coded in it.

Comment: You might want to include a link to the library that sketch uses. Given how specific your question is, you might not get much help here. (Your potential pool of help is going to be people who have used the same sensor, with the same library, using the same sketch.) I'd suggest contacting the author of the sketch.

Comment: BTW, how does that sensor work? Every pulse-ox sensor I've ever seen shines a red light through a finger or other body part, and puts a sensor on the other side. That sensor doesn't appear to have separate emitter and sensor parts.

Comment: @DuncanC - This sensor has a visible light LED, IR LED and a Photodiode all built in :)

Comment: Ok, but it doesn't have a gap into which you would put your finger. Does it shine light into your body and then measure the light reflected back?

Comment: @DuncanC - All you have to do is put your finger on the sensor. https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX30100.pdf